# SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Tags: sql, oracle10g, sql-update

I am trying to update a table with data from another table.
Data is made up in an attempt to keep it simple

**PROJECT** (table)

```
ID   FK_INCIDENT-ID  DAYS
---------------------------
01   10              0
02   20              0
```

**INCIDENT** (table)

```
ID  FK_PRIORITY-ID
------------------
10  100
20  200
```

**PRIORITY** (table)

```
ID   DAYS
---------
100  1
200  2
```

What I need to do is copy DAYS from PRIORITY over to DAYS in PROJECT with INCIDENT tying them together.

after update to PROJECT table it should look like so

```
ID   FK_INCIDENT-ID   DAYS
---------------------------
01   10               1
02   20               2
```

the only tie PROJECT has to PRIORITY is through INCIDENT.

FK_INCIDENT-ID (in PROJECT) to FK_PRIORITY-ID (in INCIDENT) to ID (in PRIORITY)

```
update (select i.ID, pro.Days, pri.Days AS Days2
from incident i
left join project pro on (i.id = pro.FK_Incident-id)
left join priority pri on (i.Fk_priority-id = pri.id)
where pro.days = 0) t
set t.Days = t.Days2
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, that the first join in your query is invalid: I think, you should replace (i.FK_Incident-id = pro.id) with (i.id = pro.FK_INCIDENT-ID).

Furthermore, [here is nice explanation on the topic of key-preserved tables](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:548422757486)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be joining your tables in the wrong order for the relationship you've described; you said:

> FK_INCIDENT-ID (in PROJECT) to FK_PRIORITY-ID (in INCIDENT) to ID (in PRIORITY)

but you're joining `INCIDENT` to `PROJECT` to `PRIORITY`.

That's why you're getting the error. There's nothing in your schema that's stopping an incident from mapping to multiple projects, and the left outer join means the same incident can appear multiple times even if it doesn't, and if it only appears once then you don't necessarily know how to get back to the right record to update.

If you re-order the in-line view query to join `PROJECT` to `INCIDENT` to `PRIORITY` then it works (with valid names):

```
update (
  select i.ID, pro.Days, pri.Days AS Days2
  from project pro
  left join incident i on (i.id = pro.incident_id)
  left join priority pri on (pri.id = i.priority_id)
  where pro.days = 0) t
set t.Days = t.Days2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/44831/1)

Why is the `days` value denormalised into the `project` table at all though? Or does it mean something else there (like actual resolution time, rather than the target from the priority), and you're just assuming the worst for projects that haven't set it? Although that would seem to fit better at `incident` level, I would have thought. Or this could all just be made up, of course...